# How to run Apache airflow that is installed by PyPy as systemd?

Tags: python, services, systemd, anaconda

I installed Apache airflow using PyPy and the executable is in

`/home/my_user/anaconda3/envs/my_env/bin/airflow`

The installation is working fine and I wanted to make it a systemd.

```
[Unit]
Description=Airflow standalon daemon
After=network.target postgresql.service mysql.service redis.service rabbitmq-server.service
Wants=postgresql.service mysql.service redis.service rabbitmq-server.service

[Service]
Environment="PATH=/home/my_user/anaconda3/my_env/dev/bin"
User=my_user
Group=my_user
Type=simple
ExecStart=/home/my_user/anaconda3/envs/my_env/bin/airflow standalone
Restart=always
RestartSec=5s

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

However, I get this error:

```
Dec 10 17:06:06 airflow[23454]:     raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
Dec 10 17:06:06 airflow[23454]: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'airflow'
```

Am I setting it up correctly?